# Fatal error: Database error in cpanel

Tags: php

I have uploaded a website to c panel. When i try to access it from my browser i get the following error:

> Fatal error: Database error 0:  linkID == False. Connect failed. in
>   Warning: mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
>   (using password: NO) in
>   /home/anyonstr/school.anyonstrendtakesolution.co.ke/classes/Database.class.php
>   on line 128
>
> Fatal error: Database error 0:  linkID == False. Connect failed. in
>   /home/anyonstr/school.anyonstrendtakesolution.co.ke/classes/Database.class.php
>   on line 173

yet it was working ok in xampp.
This is my code here,

```
class Database
{
# Constructor. Create an instance of this class with this.
# You would generally need just one.


private static $_singleton;
private $linkID;
private function __construct($hostname, $username, $password,            
$database, 
$debug=False){
    $this->debug = $debug;
    $this->linkID = 0;
    $this->queryID = 0;
    $this->queryCount = 0;
    $this->errNo = 0;
    $this->errStr = '';

    //$this->_connection = mysql_connect();
     if (! ($hostname and $username and $database))
        $this->halt('Missing parameters.');

    $this->linkID = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password);

    if (! $this->linkID)
        $this->halt('linkID == False. Connect failed.');

    if (! mysql_select_db($database, $this->linkID))
        $this->halt("Cannot use database '$database'.");

   }
   public static function getInstance($hostname, $username, $password, 
  $database, $debug=False){
    if (is_null (self::$_singleton)) {
        self::$_singleton = new Database($hostname, $username, $password, 
  $database, $debug=False);
    }
    return self::$_singleton;
    }


   /*  function Database($hostname, $username, $password, $database, 
   $debug=False)
   {
    $this->debug = $debug;
    $this->linkID = 0;
    $this->queryID = 0;
    $this->queryCount = 0;
    $this->errNo = 0;
    $this->errStr = '';

    if (! ($hostname and $username and $database))
        $this->halt('Missing parameters.');


    $this->linkID = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password);


    if (! $this->linkID)
        $this->halt('linkID == False. Connect failed.');

    if (! mysql_select_db($database, $this->linkID))
        $this->halt("Cannot use database '$database'.");
    }*/

    # Halt because an error occured.
    function halt($msg)
   {
    trigger_error(
        sprintf("Database error %d: %s<br />%s\n",
                $this->errNo, $this->errStr, $msg),
        E_USER_ERROR);
    }
```

help me solve the problem

Comment: line 128 is  $this->linkID = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password); and line 173 is  E_USER_ERROR);

Comment: Are you getting an error in cpanel or an error in your code? They are not the same thing.

Comment: Am getting the error from the browser when trying to load my website